# Pytest Selenium - Selecting Elements As List

Tags: python, selenium

I have a webpage containing inventory_container that has multiple elements under it (products).

I want to ask if there is a way to select all child elements under 1 specific as a list and select them as I please for example, by text or class.

[example for elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrprr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inventory_items = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'inventory_item')
print(len(inventory_items)
for each_item in inventory_items:
    your code here
```

Comment: this code may work, but it'll also select all other `li`'s with the class `inventory_item`

Comment: This actually works, but for some reason it returns the first element six times, how do I solve that?

Comment: I use the following code and it gets the first instance the number of times the class exist:
    ``def inventory_l(self):
        
        r = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='inventory_list']")
        
       return r.find_elements_by_xpath(".//div[@class='inventory_item']")``

Comment: @nadavlevin Is it possible to share the website link? That way it would be easy to inspect the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this buy reached the parent first then looking for direct childs only for this you can use css-selector.

```
inventory_items = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[class="inventory_list"] > div')
```

Now you have a list of web elements you can iterate each child element in loop.

Comment: This actually works, but for some reason it returns the first element six times, how do I solve that?